# Which equals method is more preferable?

Tags: java

Another strange question, I have two implementations of equals method
Whcih implementation is more preferable and why?

```
 @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        Test other = (Test) o;

        return id == other.id;

    }
```

Or this,

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (o instanceof Test) {
       Test other = (Test) o;
       return id == other.id;
}
 return false;
}
```

Please note, the class is not final.

Comment: What do you mean by "preferable"?  Faster? Just benchmark them. Clearer? A matter of opinion mostly.

Comment: 1st one is correct one. 2nd one is broken, because you can pass subclass of Test and it could lead to asymmetric equality.

Comment: ... and because this is a matter of opinion, it is unfortunately off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Mostly +1 to @IlyaBursov. If you _do_ want to accept subtypes (which is sometimes reasonable), you should make equals/hashCode final, so that subtypes can't change the equality contract.

Comment: I got the answer, thans @IlyaBursov . The second one breaks the symmetric equality principle, so it is really a bug.

Comment: The class is not final and it so we can subclass it and break the rule easily with the second implementation .

Comment: By the way, Josh Bloch [prefers using `instanceof` instead](http://www.artima.com/intv/bloch17.html).

Comment: @IlyaBursov Note that the second pattern does make sense in the context of interface-level equivalence contracts, as the Java Collections describe.

Comment: @JoeC Whether it's right or wrong depends on contract (interface-level equality vs. instance-based equality); since correctness can be defined in technical terms (based on use case), I'd say it's on-topic.

Comment: As Joshua Bloch points out, #1 violates LSV. You shouldn't write bad object-oriented code (violating LSV) because you're worried about other people writing bad object-oriented code (overriding `equals` to add other stuff, and thus also violating LSV).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: I hope `id` here is a primitive, otherwise you should be using `id.equals`.

Depends on your goal (just evaluating functionality here - if you want performance, you should try out in a real-world scenario, and the differences are very likely negligible).

Your first case: Tests `getClass() == o.getClass()`. This is a strict type equivalence, and is useful when dealing with subclasses. With this pattern, subtype instances will never be equal to supertype instances, and vice versa (though, a subtype can still invoke `super.equals` to test parent field equivalence). This is the usual pattern I see, and it allows subtypes to define more specific `equals` semantics comparing more fields (more on this below).

Your second case: Tests `o instanceof Test`. Notably, that means that a `Test` instance *will* test equivalent to `Test` subtype instances, as long as they match the original in `id`. Java `equals` should be implemented in a symmetric and transitive way; this implies that if `this.equals(o)`, then `o.equals` and `this.equals` must be functionally identical, *even if `o` is an instance of a `Test` subtype*.

This is usually used for `equals` semantics at interface/contract level - for instance, `List`s, `Set`s and `Map`s define notions of equivalence all subtypes must satisfy, so that different `List` implementations can be compared to each other.

[EDIT: Both `.equals` and `.hashCode` should be made final in this case, to prevent subtypes from redefining semantics - thanks @yshavit.]

TLDR: If you're not sure, use the first unless you're *very* sure you need the second.